# jQuery - How to translate a Scriptaculous toggle in a jQuery slidetoggle?

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple question (I guess!)

I used to work with Scriptaculous to add DOM effects to my pages
Now that I also use jQuery, it seems to be a conflict between Scriptaculous and jQuery

How can I translate this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="Effect.toggle('header', 'blind', { duration: 1.0 }); return false;">link</a>
```

to a jQuery similar effect? (`SlideToggle()` maybe?)

```
<a href="#" onclick="???; return false;">link</a>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onclick = "javascript:$('#header').toggle(100);"
```

Assuming you have a element with id as header. The parameter 100 is the milliseconds for the toggle transition. You can also call slideToggle().

Answer (score 0):

For a start, it's better practice not to use the onclick attribute, but to assign click handlers in your document ready event. This keeps your markup and its behaviour separate. So your link would become:

```
<a href="#" class="toggleheader">link</a>
```

and your document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.toggleheader').click(function()
    {
        $('#header').slideToggle('slow');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Garteh: Thank you Gareth, where do I need to insert my document ready event? (I have a main.js with all my js functions, and a main.css)

Comment: @jrm You should put it in your main.js file.